# how can i Return an error when typing neither Y/N?

Tags: java

How do i return an error and ask the question Do you want to try again (Y/N)? again when the user entered neither Y/N as an answer?

```
package randomgenerate;
/**
 *
 * @author Trung
 */
public class World {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int max=0;
        int min=0;
        double aver = 0;
        int option;
        rg a = new rg();
        a.generate();
        a.count();
        System.out.println("Max number is "+ a.maximum(max));
        System.out.println("Average number is "+ a.average(aver));
        System.out.println("Min number is "+ a.minimum(min));
        System.out.println("Do you want to run it again (y/n)?: ");
        option = a.getchoice();
        switch (option)
        {
            case 1:
            {
            a.generate();
            a.count();
            System.out.println("Max number is "+ a.maximum(max));
            System.out.println("Average number is "+ a.average(aver));
            System.out.println("Min number is "+ a.minimum(min));
            System.out.println("Do you want to run it again (y/n)?: ");
            option = a.getchoice();
            }
            case 2:
            {
            System.out.println("Program exits.");
            System.exit(0);
            }
            case 3:
            {
            System.out.println("Invalid. Please enter gyh or gnh: ");
            a.getchoice();
            }
        }
    }
}

package randomgenerate;

import java.util.Scanner;

/**
 *
 * @author Trung
 */
public class rg {
    //generate 100 random number
        int s[]= new int[101];
    public void generate (){
            int i, random;
            System.out.println("Generating 100 random integers between 0 and 9");
            for (i=1; i<=100;i++)
            {
                s[i] = (int)(Math.random()*10+0);

                System.out.println("Number "+i+" = "+ s[i]);
            }
        }
    //count
        public void count (){
            int i;
            int count0=0;
            int count1=0;
            int count2=0;
            int count3=0;
            int count4=0;
            int count5=0;
            int count6=0;
            int count7=0;
            int count8=0;
            int count9=0;
            for (i=1; i<=100; i++)
            {
                if (s[i]==0)
                {
                    count0++;
                }
                else if (s[i]==1)
                {
                    count1++;
                }
                else if (s[i]==2)
                {
                    count2++;
                }
                else if (s[i]==3)
                {
                    count3++;
                }
                else if (s[i]==4)
                {
                    count4++;
                }
                else if (s[i]==5)
                {
                    count5++;
                }
                else if (s[i]==6)
                {
                    count6++;
                }
                else if (s[i]==7)
                {
                    count7++;
                }
                else if (s[i]==8)
                {
                    count8++;
                }
                else if (s[i]==9)
                {
                    count9++;
                }
            }
            if (count0 <= 1)
            {
                System.out.println("0 occurs "+ count0 + " time");
            }
            else
            {
                System.out.println("0 occurs "+ count0 + " times");
            }
            if (count1 <= 1)
            {
                System.out.println("1 occurs "+ count1 + " time");
            }
            else
            {
                System.out.println("1 occurs "+ count1 + " times");
            }
            if (count2 <= 1)
            {
                System.out.println("2 occurs "+ count2 + " time");
            }
            else
            {
                System.out.println("2 occurs "+ count2 + " times");
            }
            if (count3 <= 1)
            {
                System.out.println("3 occurs "+ count3 + " time");
            }
            else
            {
                System.out.println("3 occurs "+ count3 + " times");
            }
            if (count4 <= 1)
            {
                System.out.println("4 occurs "+ count4 + " time");
            }
            else
            {
                System.out.println("4 occurs "+ count4 + " times");
            }
            if (count5 <= 1)
            {
                System.out.println("5 occurs "+ count5 + " time");
            }
            else
            {
                System.out.println("5 occurs "+ count5 + " times");
            }
            if (count6 <= 1)
            {
                System.out.println("6 occurs "+ count6 + " time");
            }
            else
            {
                System.out.println("6 occurs "+ count6 + " times");
            }
            if (count7 <= 1)
            {
                System.out.println("7 occurs "+ count7 + " time");
            }
            else
            {
                System.out.println("7 occurs "+ count7 + " times");
            }
            if (count8 <= 1)
            {
                System.out.println("8 occurs "+ count8 + " time");
            }
            else
            {
                System.out.println("8 occurs "+ count8 + " times");
            }
            if (count9 <= 1)
            {
                System.out.println("9 occurs "+ count9 + " time");
            }
            else
            {
                System.out.println("9 occurs "+ count9 + " times");
            }
        }
        public int maximum (int max)
        {
            max = s[0];
            for (int i=1;i<=100;i++)
            {
                if(max<s[i])
                {
                    max=s[i];
                }
            }
            return (max);
        }
        public int minimum (int min)
        {
            min = s[0];
            for (int i=1;i<=100;i++)
            {
                if(s[i]<min)
                {
                    min=s[i];
                }
            }
            return (min);
        }
        public double average (double aver)
        {
            int i = 1;
            int subtotal1 = 0;
            int subtotal2 = 0;
            int subtotal3 = 0;
            int subtotal4 = 0;
            int subtotal5 = 0;
            int subtotal6 = 0;
            int subtotal7 = 0;
            int subtotal8 = 0;
            int subtotal9 = 0;
            for (i=1;i<=100;i++)
            {
                if (s[i]==1)
                {
                    subtotal1 = subtotal1 + s[i];
                }
                else if (s[i]==2)
                {
                    subtotal2 = subtotal2 +s[i];
                }
                else if (s[i]==3)
                {
                    subtotal3 = subtotal3 +s[i];
                }
                else if (s[i]==4)
                {
                    subtotal4 = subtotal4 +s[i];
                }
                else if (s[i]==5)
                {
                    subtotal5 = subtotal5 +s[i];
                }
                else if (s[i]==6)
                {
                    subtotal6 = subtotal6 +s[i];
                }
                else if (s[i]==7)
                {
                    subtotal7 = subtotal7 +s[i];
                }
                else if (s[i]==8)
                {
                    subtotal8 = subtotal8 +s[i];
                }
                else if (s[i]==9)
                {
                    subtotal9 = subtotal9 +s[i];
                }
            }
            aver = (subtotal1 + subtotal2 + subtotal3 + subtotal4 + subtotal5 + subtotal6 + subtotal7 + subtotal8 + subtotal9) * 0.01;
            return (aver);
        }
        public int getchoice() {
                Scanner reader = new Scanner(System.in);
                String selection = reader.nextLine();
        if (selection.equals("y") || selection.equals("Y")){
                    return 1;
                }
                else if (selection.equals("n") || selection.equals("N")){
                    return 2;
                }
                else
                {
                    return 3;
                }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please only include the important part of the code. Noone is going to investigate hundreds of lines.

Comment: Try to shorten your code so only the relevant parts are in the question, we dont need your whole program if it is not related to the question. Also typing your question two times makes no sense

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can just add in the `getchoice()` method :

```
if(!selection.toLowerCase().equals("y") && !selection.toLowerCase().equals("n") ){
    System.out.println("Error");
    return this.getchoice();
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Try something like this:

```
while(true){
    System.out.println("Do you want to try again (Y/N)?");
    String input = reader.nextLine();
    if(input.equals("N"))
        break;
    else 
        continue;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.println("Do you want to run it again (y/n)?: ");
while (!(sc.hasNext() && ((sc.nextLine().equalsIgnoreCase("y"))||
        sc.nextLine().equalsIgnoreCase("n")))){
    System.out.println("Do you want to run it again (y/n)?: ");
    // other code
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, refactor the code into a method. Then you can call the method anywhere in your program (currently, you call it twice, so you can replace both versions with this version.

Then, add a loop...

```
public static int getRunAgain(rg a) {
    int option = 3;

    System.out.println("Max number is "+ a.maximum(max));
    System.out.println("Average number is "+ a.average(aver));
    System.out.println("Min number is "+ a.minimum(min));

    while(true) {
        System.out.println("Do you want to run it again (y/n)?: ");
        option = a.getchoice();
        if (option != 3) break;
        System.out.println("Invalid. Please enter y/n. ");
    }
    return option;
 }
```

An alternative method would be to put the loop inside the `getChoice` method.

Answer (score 0):

```
do
{
System.out.println("Max number is "+ a.maximum(max));
System.out.println("Average number is "+ a.average(aver));
System.out.println("Min number is "+ a.minimum(min));
System.out.println("Do you want to run it again (y/n)?: ");
option = a.getchoice();
}while(option.equals("Y") || !option.equals("N"));
```

If user enters Y, it will repeat. Aslo, if he enters neither "Y" nor "N", then it will repeat too.